# How to concatenate a string to each element of a list of strings?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have the following list:

```
sentence = ['doc1','doc2','doc3','doc4']
```

How can I concatenate `.txt` at the end of each elment of `sentece`? (*):

```
['doc1.txt','doc2.txt','doc3.txt','doc4.txt']
```

I tried to list comprehension:

```
'.txt '.join(sentence[:-1])
```

Nonetheless, it returns this:

```
'doc1.txt doc2.txt doc3'
```

Which is wrong, since it's different from (*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't trying to join the whole string together just add `.txt` to each string:

```
>>> [s + '.txt' for s in sentence]
['doc1.txt', 'doc2.txt', 'doc3.txt', 'doc4.txt']
```

Not sure why you are slicing off the last element.

Comment: I see... thanks for helping me to clarify this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach :

```
>>> sentence = ['doc1','doc2','doc3','doc4']
>>> list(map(lambda x : x + '.txt', sentence))
['doc1.txt', 'doc2.txt', 'doc3.txt', 'doc4.txt']
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use map and lambda

```
map(lambda x:x+'.txt', sentence)
```

output:

```
['doc1.txt', 'doc2.txt', 'doc3.txt', 'doc4.txt']
```